# How to check NULL value for geometry data type in Where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geometry, gis, spatial

I am working in a app to store polygon data in a SQL Server database. I already have a table where I add a column

```
ALTER TABLE SpatialTable ADD PolygonGeometry geometry Null
ALTER TABLE SpatialTable ADD DEFAULT geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (0 0)', 0) FOR PolygonGeometry
```

Since this table already contains data so I have to update `PolygonGeometry` column with default value, so I have an update query as below.

```
UPDATE SpatialTable 
SET PolygonGeometry = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (0 0)', 0)
```

I want to apply a where clause that is:

```
 WHERE PolygonGeometry1.STEquals(Null) = Null
```

But this does not work.

How could I update Null values of geometry column in a table?

Comment: Nothing equals  (`=`)`NULL`, including `NULL`, nor does anything not equal (`!=`) `NULL`. If you need to compare to an expression that returns `NULL`, use `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: "Since this table already contains data so I have to update column with default value." Do you? You could leave it as `NULL` if you wanted to. Or, if you're going to set every existing column to a static point (in your case, `(0, 0)`), create the column with a default constraint so that it's a metadata change rather than a size-of-table change.

Comment: @BenThul I have added this
ALTER TABLE SpatialTable ADD DEFAULT geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (0 0)', 0) FOR PolygonGeometry
for default constraint so that meta change.

Comment: Good. What rows are you trying to update then?

Comment: All those rows, which are already there in the table.